# HTML Form Post action

Tags: php, html

I have a Form

```
<form name="frmRegCo" method="post" action="business_processor.php">
```

the business_processor.php inserts data into mysql db what i want is that when i click submit the page should not redirect to the business_processor.php and remain on the same form window but the data must be sent to the mysql DB and a popup box must appear that data sent successful and also after the popup box the form fields get empty

Comment: You need to use Ajax in order to have such thing.

Comment: Sounds like you need to submit the form via AJAX. The answer is long and somewhat complicated, but here's a good resource to help you get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: then you should use ajax to send data to database.

Comment: If you're starting your post with `Dear All` and closing it with `Regards`, then atleast use `I` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways.

1) Place PHP code in this same document.

2) Use AJAX. [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

This is were AJAX comes in place. It sends the data in the background without changing the current page.

I suggest having a look at the [jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and maybe [at a short tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):
Example:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: business_processor.php,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response != '') {
                             //popup box message
                        } 
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to just do following

```
<form name="frmRegCo" method="post" action="">
```

and Just Copy your `business_processor.php` code to the current file.

**OR**

Use `AJAX`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: business_processor.php,
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
        if(response != '') {
            //popup box message
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want remain on the same form window then try this. define this code in top of the page.

```
<?php
     if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit')
     {
         //insert query here
     }
?>

<form name="frmRegCo" method="post" action="">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**OR** you can use `AJAX` to achive what you want.

Comment: isset($_POST['submit']) return only boolean with true or false.. not a string

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). 
JQuery is a good java script library that can help you with cross browser development of the feature. See [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

if form is inside same page (i.e business_processor.php) then just declare form as below,

```
<form action="" method = "" ></form>
```

else if not same page then add below code insied `business_processor.php`

```
form_process code
header('location: yourFormPage.php');
exit;
```